# Merging columns from 2 different tables to apply aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, merge

I have below 3 Tables

```
Create table products(
  prod_id character(20) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT prod_pkey PRIMARY KEY (prod_id)
)
Create table dress_Sales(
  prod_id character(20) NOT NULL,
  dress_amount numeric(7,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT prod_pkey PRIMARY KEY (prod_id),
  CONSTRAINT prod_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (prod_id)
  REFERENCES products (prod_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
Create table sports_Sales(
  prod_id character(20) NOT NULL,
  sports_amount numeric(7,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT prod_pkey PRIMARY KEY (prod_id),
  CONSTRAINT prod_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (prod_id)
  REFERENCES products (prod_id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I want to get the `Sum` and `Average` sales amount form both the tables(Only for the Selected `Prod_id`). I have tried the below code but it's not producing any value.

```
select sum(coalesce(b.dress_amount, c.sports_amount)) as total_Amount
from products a JOIN dress_sales b on a.prod_id = b.prod_id 
JOIN sports_sales c on a.prod_id = c.prod_id and a.prod_id = ANY( {"123456","456789"}')`
```

Here `1000038923` is in dress_sales table and `8002265822` is in sports_sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your product can exist in only one table (`dress_sales` or `sports_sales`).

In this case you should use `left join`:

```
select
        sum(coalesce(b.dress_amount, c.sports_amount)) as total_amount,
        avg(coalesce(b.dress_amount, c.sports_amount)) as avg_amount
    from products a
    left join dress_sales b using(prod_id)
    left join sports_sales c using(prod_id)
        where
            a.prod_id in ('1', '2');
```

If you use `inner join` (which is default) the product row will not appear in the result set as it will not be joined with either `dress_sales` or `sports_sales`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a product that appears in both tables you can use a subquery that can handle both `dress_amount` and `sports_amount` values.

```
select sum(combined.amount), avg(combined.amount)
from
  (select prod_id, dress_amount as amount from dress_sales
   union all
   select prod_id, sports_amount as amount from sports_sales) combined
where
   combined.prod_id in ('1','2');
```